# Find the necessity and sufficiency condition for $Z_m$ to be a Field

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a group like $Z_m =   \{0,1,2,...,m-1 \}$ and define an addition and multiplication on this group as the remainder of ordinary addition and multiplication division by $m$ (modulo m),
prove that the necessity and sufficiency condition for $Z_m$ to be a Field is that the $m$ be a prime number!

e.g.: $$m=5$$
$$2\oplus4=1$$
$$2\otimes4=3$$

for $$m=2$$
I guess it's like Boolean algebra!

Comment: What have you tried?  If $m$ is composite, can you find a field axiom that fails?

Comment: Use the Bezout identity to show the multiplication by $a$ works well when $\gcd(a,m)=1$